# Parallel inserting with NHibernate

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, parallel-processing, etl

Scenario:

Need to load lots of entities from an integration database to the production database. We load things into our prod DB using NHibernate because the business rules involved are already written in C# using our persistent entities. Everything runs fine, we load our valid entities into the DB. The RDBMS is SQL Server 2005 (could be upgraded to 2008).

The problem:

The number of entities to load will grow insanely soon and we are pretty sure that it will take longer than expected and fail to meet our customer's requirements.

The solution (?):

It is easy to simply run things in parallel: split all entities into buckets and import them in parallel.

The problem is that they all insert into the same table and all the process would bottleneck in table locks.

So the question is: is there a way to make these inserts in a way that doesn't lock the table for other transactions trying to insert in the same table? I heard of snapshot isolation level, but did not found anyone using it for real. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think the chapter [10.4 Optimistic concurrency control](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-10-transactions-and/1nr4enxv3dpeq/13#10%282E%294%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Optimistic_concurrency_control) should help you to get your things done. You can define an explicit Isolation-Level for this type of Insert. The article suggests to use versioning but if you don't need this cause you data are only inserts but no updates you can skip that. In this case last commit wins.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to insert into different tables (one per "bucket" as described) and join them in a view?  The customer wouldn't see a difference except the loading times just dropped by 80%...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with NHibernate, but from .NET you can bulk load data in parallel using SqlBulkCopy (or use BULK INSERT / BCP). Apply TABLOCK on the table being loaded and these bulk operations take out Bulk Update locks on the table, and if you have 2 processes with Bulk Update locks, they will get along just fine. You'd need to be loading into a heap (no clustered index on the table).

This is as opposed to if you have multiple processes doing INSERT...SELECT for example which would acquire exclusive, table level locks and so would block each other.

I recommend [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) - a lot more detail and info in there. Hopefully this kind of thing will be possible for you.

Also, if you can, remove indexes from the table before loading and then recreate them afterwards - that will improve the loading speed.

Comment: The scenario is delicate because the system must stay online during the batch load

Answer (score 1):

"Do one thing with the right tool"

Don't use NHibernate to do bulk insert, use plain ADO.NET command and bulk inserts

Comment: @Pedro: This approach doesn't necessarily imply you'll have to duplicate your business rules. Nothing's stopping you from creating domain entities, checking validation, and then populating the validated data out to a DataTable for bulk insertion.